# Native method not found org.opencv.core.mat.n_mat-Android

Tags: android, opencv, unsatisfiedlinkerror, native-methods

I followed all steps when dealing with Mat including adding it to AsyncTask when calling but still the same error which is native method not found org.opencv.core.mat.n_mat

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

import com.example.myfirstapp.RegisterMarkerMain.ProcessImage;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class CreateApp extends ListActivity {

    boolean duplicate = false;
    String userID = "";
    Intent manage;
    String image = "";
    Intent refresh;
    CandidatesListAdapter adapter;
    ProcessImage process;
    Mat mRgba;
    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            Log.i("loading libs", "OpenCV loading status " + status);
            switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                Log.i("loading libs", "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                System.loadLibrary("native_sample");

            }
                break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_app);
        manage = new Intent(this, ManageApps.class);
        concurrentTasks();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            userID = extras.getString("user_id");
            Toast.makeText(CreateApp.this, "User id " + userID,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.categories_spinner);
        refresh = new Intent(this, ManageApps.class);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.categories_array,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
                    View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                // your code here
                String category = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Toast.makeText(CreateApp.this,
                        "Category " + category + " selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_title);
                tv.setText(category);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.application_logo);
        registerForContextMenu(iv);
        iv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });

        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(CreateApp.this, "Long click to add image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.application_name_edit);
                if (et.getText().toString().equals(null)
                        || et.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateApp.this,
                            "App Name can not be empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select")
                            || spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(CreateApp.this,
                                "Cateory must be selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    } else {
                        new AsyncAppDuplicates().execute();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (duplicate == true) {
                            System.out
                                    .println("Duplicate flag for App Creation inside if "
                                            + duplicate);
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    CreateApp.this);
                            builder.setTitle("Warning");
                            builder.setMessage("An application already exists with this name."
                                    + "\n" + "Please choose a different name.");
                            builder.setNegativeButton("Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            // if this button is clicked, just
                                            // close
                                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                            builder.show();
                        } else {
                            concurrentCreate();
                            Toast.makeText(CreateApp.this,
                                    "Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            System.out.println("Done");
                            // EditText app = (EditText)
                            // findViewById(R.id.application_name_edit);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void concurrentTasks() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            new AsyncGetCategories()
                    .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

            System.out.println("getting categories");
        } else {
            new AsyncGetCategories().execute();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void concurrentCreate() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            new AsyncCreateApplication()
                    .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

            System.out.println("Creating app");
        } else {
            new AsyncCreateApplication().execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            finish();
            manage.putExtra("user_id", userID);
            startActivity(manage);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_app, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextmenu, menu);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select an Option");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_take:
            Toast.makeText(CreateApp.this, "Opening the Camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent camera = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(camera, 0);
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_choose:
            Toast.makeText(CreateApp.this, "Opening the Gallery",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent gallery = new Intent();
            gallery.setType("image/*");
            gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Select Picture"), 1);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Adding Photo From Camera",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.application_logo);
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                iv.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                Intent r = new Intent(this, RegisterMarkerMain.class);
                //startActivity(r);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); 
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                image = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                //r.putExtra("BitmapImage", image);
                //startActivityForResult(r, 13);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Marker Valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                adapter = new CandidatesListAdapter(this);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                process = new ProcessImage(this, thumbnail);
                process.execute();
                //call the main layout from xml
                //RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.create_layout_id);

                //create a view to inflate the layout_item (the xml with the textView created before)
                //View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_item, mainLayout,false);

                //add the view to the main layout
               // mainLayout.addView(view);
            }

            break;
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Adding Photo From Gallery",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Uri targetUri = data.getData();
                iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.application_logo);
                Bitmap thumbnail = null;
                try {
                    thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                            .openInputStream(targetUri));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                iv.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos);
                byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();;
                try{
                System.gc();
                image=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
                    baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50, baos);
                    b=baos.toByteArray();
                    image=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Log.e("EWN", "Out of memory error catched");
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, "Marker Valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    public void managePrivacy(View v) {
        Intent privacyIntent = new Intent(this, ManagePrivactActivity.class);
        startActivity(privacyIntent);
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Marker o = (Marker) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, "strength " + o.descriptor.rows(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // TODO: both Image and descriptor should be sent to server combined
        // with location and other info.
        // Descriptor of image is n rows * 64 numbers
    }

    public native void loadCand(long nativeObjAddr, long descriptoradd, int i);

    public native int findMarkersNative(long imgAdd);

    public class ProcessImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Marker>> {


        private Context mContext;
        Bitmap bmp;

        public ProcessImage(Context context, Bitmap bmp) {
            mContext = context;
            mRgba = new Mat();
            this.bmp = bmp;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            getListView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, mRgba);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Marker> result) {
            getListView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter.updateData(result);
            // display

            Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);

            //imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Marker> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<Marker> imagesCand = new ArrayList<Marker>();
            // process
            int candCount = findMarkersNative(mRgba.getNativeObjAddr());

            for (int i = 0; i < candCount; i++) {
                Mat cand = new Mat();
                Mat descriptor = new Mat();

                loadCand(cand.getNativeObjAddr(),
                        descriptor.getNativeObjAddr(), i);
                if (descriptor.rows() > 0) {
                    Bitmap bmp3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(cand.cols(), cand.rows(),
                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Utils.matToBitmap(cand, bmp3);
                    imagesCand.add(new Marker(bmp3, descriptor));
                }
            }
            return imagesCand;
        }

    }

    private class AsyncCreateApplication extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.application_name_edit);
            String s = et.getText().toString();
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_title);
            String c = tv.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("Category yafanan " + c);
            ServerAPI.createApplication(s, c, userID, image);
            System.out.println("in Background");
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.application_name_edit);
            refresh.putExtra("app_name", et.getText().toString());
            System.out.println("App created " + et.getText().toString());
            refresh.putExtra("user_id", userID);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, refresh);
            // startActivity(edit);
            startActivity(refresh);
        }

    }

    private class AsyncGetCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ArrayList<String> al = null;
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
        Spinner category = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.categories_spinner);

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            System.out.println("do in background");
            al = ServerAPI.getCategories();
            System.out.println("ArrayList fetched");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CreateApp.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    new ArrayList<String>());
            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            category.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            dataAdapter.add("Select");
            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                dataAdapter.add(al.get(i));
                // System.out.println(al.remove(i));
            }

            return;
        }

    }

    private class AsyncAppDuplicates extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.application_name_edit);
            String name = et.getText().toString();

            String s = ServerAPI.checkAppDuplicates(name, userID);
            System.out.println("Checked and " + s);
            if (s.equals("Already there")) {
                duplicate = true;
            } else {
                duplicate = false;
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

I've googled so much but I can't figure out what's wrong.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it writing the following lines where you declare everything for the activity, before onCreate:

```
static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        // Handle initialization error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

confirm your native_sample.so file has been contained in your libs-->armeabi folder, and usually, the native lib should be loaded in a static code block outside of the activity's life circle methods.

Comment: I found some naming mistakes which solved this part but another problem has occurred with no solution to it till now. Your help would be really appreciated if you know anything.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409425/unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method-not-found-android/